# How to prevent mcrypt_encrypt() from failing to encrypt larger file?

Tags: php, encryption, error-log, php-ini

I'm trying to encrypt an uploaded file using a PHP script similar to [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#example-882). It works fine with smaller files, but when I try to upload a test file that is 49.2 MB in size (which is not that big by today's standards) the following causes my php page to display a blank page by terminating the script:

```
$binaryFileData = file_get_contents($serverFilePath);
$binaryEncFile = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $binaryKey, $binaryFileData, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $binaryIV);
```

I get a line in the `error_log` file that says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 51694736 bytes) in
>   /home2/myaccount/public_html/myfldr/myfile.inc on line 620

Line 620 points to `mcrypt_encrypt` in my example above.

So I did some research and people suggested adding the following to the `php.ini` file:

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Which I did, but it still resulted in the same outcome.

So I have a two-part question:

1. Obviously, how to prevent that exception from terminating my script?
2. Is there any way to make that function return an error, or throw an exception that I can catch instead of just terminating (and resulting in a white/blank page shown to a user?)

I need to resolve item 2 above also to be able to delete an un-encrypted file off the server if encryption fails (which I obviously can't do if `mcrypt_encrypt` simply terminates my script.

PS. I need to say that I run this script on a shared account hosted with BlueHost.

Comment: Your ISP may have disabled changing the memory limit to share resources among many clients. Maybe you need to pay more.

Comment: @HoboSapiens: Hmm. May be. But if that's the case the `mcrypt_encrypt` function is kinda useless, isn't it? Also, I'm curious, since loading the whole file into RAM and encrypting it like that might actually be a bad idea, is there a way to do it block-by-block? Or in other words, by reading, encrypting and writing small chunks of a file, one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ini_set(“memory_limit”,”640M“);
```

To set the memory limit to a higher limit.
The above increases the limit from your 128MB to 640Mb.

If you still encounter problems, use

```
realpath_cache_size = 16k
realpath_cache_ttl = 120
```

Note that in php 5.3 and after you can simply put an user.ini file (with the line memory_limit = 640M) in the public_html directory, but this is not allowed by all cpanels.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, why is setting it via `ini_set` has an effect while changing it via `php.ini` does not?

Comment: Some setups ignore (unfortunately) .ini file settings. The tendency today is to support them as much as possible, because general configs can be written very easy via .inis.

Comment: I see. What about my 2nd question -- is there a way to prevent that function from terminating the script if I go over the limit?

Comment: I think you could do something to pause it before the termination happens. You could use the mem-size related function to detect when occupied memory approaches allocated memory and use a halt before the limit is reached.

Comment: Hmm. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround would be to encrypt the file in small chunks (like 4128 bytes at a time).

Sample code:

```
$fr=fopen('input.file','r');
$fw=fopen('output.file','w');
while(!feof($fr))
{
    $buffer=fread($fr,4128);
    $result=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $binaryKey, $buffer, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $binaryIV);
    false!==$result && fwrite($fw,$result);
}
fclose($fw);
fclose($fr);
```

That way you end-up with a encrypted file that later can be decrypted by reversing these steps.

Note that the chunk size 4128 it's not randomly chosen. Knowing that RIJNDAEL supports blocks of 128/192/256 bits (ie. 16/24/32 bytes) I determined the LCM between these numbers (that is 96) and then I chose any chunk size (around 4K) that is multiple of 96. It happened that 4128 met the criteria.

Why is the chunk size important? Because MCrypt divides your input text in fixed blocks of your-block-size length and if there is a reminder then it pads that space with zeros until the block length divides exactly. So we don't want to let MCrypt to do that, right? Anyway, keep in mind that it will do so for the last block of your file (unless you are fortunate enough such that it is already multiple of your-block-size.

I hope it helps...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about 4128 bytes, or any hard-coded value, but that's the approach that I ended up using, i.e. encrypting in chunks. The important thing to note is that the size of each encryption chunk must be a multiple of the cipher block size. One could get it by calling `mcrypt_get_iv_size`, for example: `$cipher_block_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);`